# If statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

In this code, the first and second controls don't work!

My idea is that if one of the fiels is empty, there's an error. In other word, all the fields are expect.

```
if(!empty($nome) && !empty($cognome) == 0)
    header("location: ./content_reg_comeunprodigio_no.html");
else if($dati_pers == 'n')
    header("location: ./content_reg_comeunprodigio_trattamentodati.html");
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO persons_comeunprodigio (nome, cognome)
                  VALUES ('$nome', '$cognome')";

    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

    header("location: ./content_reg_comeunprodigio_ok.html");
}
```

Thank u in advance!

Comment: Where are the variables assigned? `$nome` and `$cognome`? can we see this please

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: So, can you post the error? we're not magicians. Also try to write maintainable code,`if(!empty($nome) && !empty($cognome) == 0)` looks like was written with the sole purpose of confusing.

Comment: if(!empty($nome) && !empty($cognome) == 0) This should have been like this if(empty($nome) || empty($cognome) == 1) And with if/else if/else statement, it works properly. Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if to

if(empty($nome) || empty($cognome) {

}

if you are testing for empty fields.  If the fields are not empty, !empty() will return true in either case (>0) and you are expecting an equality of 0, which I think is the opposite of your intent.

You do not give enough information about $dati_pers to analyze.

Comment: if(!empty($nome) && !empty($cognome) == 0) This should have been like this if(empty($nome) || empty($cognome) == 1) And with if/else if/else statement, it works properly. Thank u.

Answer (score -1):

Best I can tell, your comparison `!empty($nome) && !empty($cognome) == 0` is the culprit. Because `!empty($cognome)` will only `== 0` if `$cognome` is not empty... probably not what you want.

You might try replacing your if/else if/else block with two if blocks. Added `die();` after the header, so PHP processing stops. You can keep your if/else if/else block as the commenter suggests if you like.

```
if( empty($nome) || empty($cognome) ){
    // $nome or $cognome is empty
    header("location: ./content_reg_comeunprodigio_no.html");
    die();
}
if($dati_pers == 'n') {
    header("location: ./content_reg_comeunprodigio_trattamentodati.html");
    die();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO persons_comeunprodigio (nome, cognome)
              VALUES ('$nome', '$cognome')";

mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

header("location: ./content_reg_comeunprodigio_ok.html");
```

Comment: The `die` pattern needs to die. It's the worst possible way to handle this. Why are you killing the script deliberately? Isn't there a more elegant way of exiting here?

Comment: How so? Without it, the header is sent to the browser but the MySQL query is still executed.

Comment: The original had the last part in an `else` clause so only one of those three blocks would get run. This seems like an unusually clumsy way of doing this.

Comment: if(!empty($nome) && !empty($cognome) == 0)
This should have been like this
    if(empty($nome) || empty($cognome) == 1)
And with if/else if/else statement, it works properly. Thank u.